# Hiyama vs Sonogashira coupling

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, transition-metals

Why is Sonogashira's coupling more feasible than Hiyama's coupling when both could occur? I have seen many examples in syntheses, here is one (the penultimate reaction): 
[image: http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/syntheses/histrionicotoxin-stork.gif]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Hiyama coupling, but it seems to me that, to afford the Hiyama product, you would need $\ce{F^-}$ in there, or some base that would attack the silicon atom.

Comment: Meaning that the transmetalation is too slow otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I'm curious as to why they didn't do the Hiyama reaction in the first place to get the natural product. As I said, not real familiar. I'm sure there's a reason.

Comment: Probably because there is a bigger tendency of the reagent to undergo Sonogashira coulping, therefore the yield would be lower.

Comment: The Sonogashira is the standard reaction to try here first and it worked. Here is one page with alternatives and indeed there is a Hiyama example (but notice that Si and Br have been swapped i.e. they couple a alkynyl halide with a vinylsiloxane): http://www.organic-chemistry.org/synthesis/C1C/chains/enynes.shtm

Comment: Sonogashira with subsequent Hiyama coulping opens great synthetic possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I will answer my question. In [Organic Chemistry Portal](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/hiyama-coupling.shtm) it is written that Hiyama coulping requires an activating agent such as fluoride ion or a base because crucial for the success of the Hiyama Coupling is the polarization of the Si-C bond. Activation of the silane with base or fluoride ions (TASF, TBAF) leading to a pentavalent silicon compound is a first necessary step. The whole mechanism is given here:
[image]

On the other hand, Sonogashira coupling doesn't require any activation and it happens preferentially in the above mentioned synthesis.